# Increase the NameNode heap memory based on NameNode logs

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, heap-memory, namenode

from the name-node logs we see the following messages about the `Detected pause in JVM`

```
INFO  util.JvmPauseMonitor (JvmPauseMonitor.java run(196)) - Detected pause in JVM or host machine (eg GC)  pause of approximately 2127ms
INFO  util.JvmPauseMonitor (JvmPauseMonitor.java run(196)) - Detected pause in JVM or host machine (eg GC)  pause of approximately 1220ms
INFO  util.JvmPauseMonitor (JvmPauseMonitor.java run(196)) - Detected pause in JVM or host machine (eg GC)  pause of approximately 1244ms
```

`Detected pause in JVM` are due  insufficient heap memory. and its a sign to increase the name-node heap size

but this messages are in `INFO` and not in `WARNING`

from the log the pause is on range `2127ms - 8730ms`

based on the logs above is it recommended to increase the name-node heap size in spite the messages are in INFO?

we also check the `FGCT/GCT` ( from `jstat -gcutil` ) values and they are:

```
FGC = 0
FGCT = 0.000
GCT = 2640.700
```